# Count the number of words within an Array or List

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I need to count the number of words within an array or a list. The reason I say array or list is because I am not sure which would be the best to use in this situation. The data is static and in a .txt file (It's actually a book). I was able to create an array and break down words from the array but for the life of me I can not count! I have tried many different ways to do this and I'm thinking since it is a string it is unable to count. I have even teetered on the edge of just printing the whole book to a listbox and counting from the listbox but, that's ridiculous.

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    //------------------------
    //GLOBAL VARIABLES:
    //------------------------
    List<string> countWords;
    string[] fileWords;
    string[] fileLines;
    char[] delim = new char[] { ' ', ',','.','?','!' };
    string path;


    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void BookTitle() // TiTleAndAuthor Method will pull the Book Title and display it.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            bookTitleLabel.Text = fileLines[i];
        }
    }

    private void BookAuthor() // TiTleAndAuthor Method will pull the Book Author and display it.
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            bookAuthorLabel.Text = fileLines[i];
        }
    }

    private void FirstLines() // FirstTenWords Method pulls the first ten words of any text file and prints the to a ListBox
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 499; i++)
        {
            wordsListBox.Items.Add(fileWords[i]);
        }
    }

    private void WordCount() // Count all the words in the file.
    {

    }  




    private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog inputFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (inputFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)        // check the file the user selected
        {
            path = inputFile.FileName;                 // save that path of the file to a string variable for later use
            StreamReader fileRead = new StreamReader(path);     // read a file at the path outlined in the path variable
            fileWords = fileRead.ReadToEnd().Split(delim); // Breakdown the text into lines of text to call them at a later date
            fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            countWords = File.ReadLines(path).ToList();
            wordsListBox.Items.Clear();

            BookTitle();
            BookAuthor();
            FirstLines();
            WordCount();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid file, please select a text file");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, why can't you just use `.Count()` extension method or `.Length` array property?  What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your actual question? You have an array of words splited by a set of delimiters. Don´t you now how to get the number of elements within that array? What about `Array.Length`?

Comment: Do you mean total word count or the count of individual words? Should "This sentence is not a very long sentence" be 8 (total number of words) or something like (this, 1), (sentence, 2), (is, 1)...? Also, why do you have "for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)"? That'll always happen exactly once, so the loop is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is useful:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File_ReadAllLines();
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            words.AddRange(line.Split(' '));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(words.Count);
    }

    private static string[] File_ReadAllLines()
    {
        return new[] {
            "The one book",
            "written by gnarf",
            "once upon a time ther werent any grammer",
            "iso 1-12122-445",
            "(c) 2012 under the hills"
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I get to the answer, a quick observation on some of the loops:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
    {
        bookAuthorLabel.Text = fileLines[i];
    }
```

This'll only run once, so it's pointless to have it in a loop (unless you intended this to actually loop through the whole list, in which case it's a bug). If this is the expected behavior, you might as well just do

```
bookAuthorLabel.Text = fileLines[1];
```

You have something similar here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        bookTitleLabel.Text = fileLines[i];
    }
```

Again, this is pointless.

Now for the answer itself. I'm not sure if you're trying to get total word count or count of individual words, so here's a code sample for doing both:

```
private static void CountWords()
    {
        const string fileName = "CountWords.txt";

        // Create a dummy file
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("This is a short sentence");
            sw.WriteLine("This is a long sentence");
        }

        string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        string[] result = text.Split(new[] { " ", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Total word count
        Console.WriteLine("Total count: " + result.Count().ToString());

        // Now to illustrate getting the count of individual words
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (string word in result)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                dictionary[word]++;
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[word] = 1;
            }
        }

        foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + dictionary[key].ToString());
        }
    }
```

This should be easy to adapt to your particular needs in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Read text file line by line. split by empty character and remove unnecessary spaces. sum this count to total.

```
        var totalWords = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("abc.txt"))
        {

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                int count = sr
                    .ReadLine()
                    .Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
                totalWords += count;
            }
```

You can also use the below code:

```
totalWords = fileRead.ReadToEnd().Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

Comment: The problem with reading line by line is the possibility of a hyphenated word  that crosses from the end of one line to the next

Comment: @juharr thanks for mentioning, but could you please give me example, I didn't get you point

Comment: means a word continuing in newline ? but for that there should be pattern to detect whether its continuation of previous word or a new word. right ?

Comment: I actually tried to demonstrate in my comment, but it didn't keep the line break.  Basically a line could end with "enlighten-" and the next line would start with "ment".

Comment: So there could be other cases too. like

hel-
{linebreak}
{linebreak}
lo